# How do we calculate the growth function for the learning model made up of two concentric circles in R^2?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Compute the growth function  mH(N) for the learning model made up of two concentric circles in  R<sup>2</sup>. Specifically,  H contains the functions, which are  +1 for  a<sup>2</sup>≤x1<sup>2</sup>+x2<sup>2</sup>≤b<sup>2</sup> and  −1 otherwise.